# Why does DateTime's AddMonths function takes Int32 parameter and not Int16

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am very curious about this thing

**Int32**

```
int addmonths_int = 10;
DateTime.Now.AddMonths(addmonths_int);
```

**Int16**

```
short addmonths_short = 10;
DateTime.Now.AddMonths(addmonths_short);
```

If we could give `Int16` as Parameter in the `AddMonths` function and also the month's value can never be more than `12` then why do `.NET Framework` uses the month as `Int32` and not `Int16`...

If is there any culture specific problem in declaring the month as `Int16`... !!??!!

I am here thinking that if `month` would have been `Int16` then it would saved some bit of length in some where .. i think `Memory Allocation`

### UPDATE

> > what would be the suggestion for DateTime.Now.Month property couldn't it be Int16 instead of Int32 ??

**IS IT ALL ONE AND THE SAME ??**

Comment: @all also this SO question might be throw some hightlight on the topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270263/converting-to-int16-int32-int64-how-do-you-know-which-one-to-choose

Comment: You can add 18 months onto a date, so an upper limit of 12 makes no sense (and if it did, `Byte` would be more appropriate than `Int16`)

Comment: @all ok i aggree with the @philippe-leybaert's and jason's concept but what would be the suggestion for `DateTime.Now.Month` property couldn't it be `Int16` instead of `Int32` ??

Comment: Again, if we were micro-optimizing, why would we stop at `Int16` when `Byte` is available?

Comment: @damien-the-unbeliever **True**

Comment: Computing with *short* on a 32-bit processor is expensive.  On Intel cores, you are either paying for the 16-bit to 32-bit conversion or the prefix opcode that says the ADD should be 16 instead of 32-bit.  The latter used to cost one CPU cycle, not sure if it still does.  The CPU cache savings you'd get out of storing 16-bits to memory is a non-issue on months.  Well, usually.

Comment: @hans-passant you saved this Question, I was about to delete this Question... By the way nice explanation it should be in Answers I think... so that i could accept it !!!   :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, it can be more than 12 months. Nothing stops you from calculating the date plus 435345 months.

As for the Int32 choice: Int32 is the native integer data type of 32 bit systems, so it is the most efficient data type to work with.

Comment: +1. Why waste 16 bits (in the case of an Int16), or 24 bits (in the case of a Byte)? Further, the assumption that you can't add more than 12 to a month is incorrect. The valid number of months might be limited to 12 (and then only if it's one-based), but you can add a large number of months to a date to calculate a new date.

Comment: @Mike: I don't understand what you mean by "wastage". Where precisely is the memory being wasted? The argument will almost certainly be enregistered, and the register is at least 32 bits wide on modern hardware. Do you really want to generate *extra code* that deals with ensuring that a 32 bit register never has a number bigger than a 16 bit integer in it? How much extra code are you willing to generate to ensure that those top 16 bits are always zero?

Comment: @Eric, I think we're violently agreeing, actually. Though I will gladly admit to your vastly superior knowledge of CLR and compiler internals--I'm just an armchair theorist, and my knowledge of how this stuff works is paltry at best. My point was that you'd use 32 bits in any case, and trying to conserve memory by allocating a smaller data type was largely pointless, especially since *the assumption regarding the method's contract was incorrect.*

Comment: @Mike: Ah, yes, then we are in violent agreement. I misunderstood the thrust of your argument. My bad!

Answer (score 3):

> If we could give Int16 as Parameter in the AddMonths function and also the month's value can never be more than 12 then why do .NET Framework uses the month as Int32 and not Int16...

Why can't you add thirteen months to today and end up with June 25, 2012?

Comment: This answer is not time invariant. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is incorrect:

> also the month's value can never be
>   more than 12

Even if you were correct, I don't think it would have bought you much using a 16-bit integer instead of a 32-bit one: probably the size of a DateTime object wouldn't change at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can add more than 12 months to a given date using the AddMonths function.

The actual restriction is as follows though;

> Months value must be between +/-120000